# Как сделать регистрацию и авторизацию при использовании httplistener c#?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование

Делаю браузерную игру, использую `httplistener` для приема входящих соеденений.

Как можно сделать регистрацию новых пользователей и авторизацию старых?

Если использовать `http listener.AuthenticationSchemes basic`, то можно добиться получения логина и пароля пользователя, но я не знаю как сделать механизм сессий так, что бы пользователи не должны были вводить пароль заново, при обновлении страницы.

Comment: Не легче ли ASP.NET MVC использовать?

Comment: браузер header "Authorization: Basic username:password" посылает?

Answer (score 0):

Неясно, с какой частью у вас возникают проблемы.

Если *listener* объявлен как:

```
    public void Start(string urlBase)
    {
        if (IsStarted)
            return;
        if (m_listener == null)
            m_listener = new HttpListener();
        m_listener.Prefixes.Add(urlBase);
        m_listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;
        IsStarted = true;
        m_listener.Start();
        m_listener.BeginGetContext(WebRequestCallback, m_listener);
    }
```

То в браузере по первому запросу всплывает окно с именем пользователя и паролем (сервер возвращает 401-Unauthorized с заголовком "WWW-Authenticate: Basic", что заставляет браузер показать диалог). Когда пользователь заполняет эти поля, браузер отправляет запрос с заголовком аутентификации: `Authorization: Basic username:password`
Во всех последующих запросах браузер сохраняет этот заголовок и больше не запрашивает имя пользователя и пароль, так что пользователи не должны при обновлении страницы вводить пароль заново. Все работает из коробки, здесь ничего не нужно делать.

После получения запроса вы можете извлечь имя пользователя и пароль с помощью:

```
HttpListenerBasicIdentity identity = (HttpListenerBasicIdentity)context.User.Identity;
Name = identity.Name;
Password = identity.Password;
```

А затем используйте хранилище сеансов, чтобы узнать, есть ли в данный момент пользователь:

```
MySessionData session = MySessionStorage.GetSession(Name, Password);
```

И в зависимости от того, был ли найден сеанс или нет, вы либо принимаете пользователя, либо показываете страницу с полями регистрации.